# Wix, create database and run migration

Tags: wpf, wix, fluent-migrator

We use [Fluent Migrator](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator) for migrating a SQL Server database in our WPF-application. Now Im making an installer with [Wix Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) and are trying to add the migration as a part of the install.

I have a Custom Action that do the Migration and a Component with a SqlDatabase-tag that creates the database. The migration works fine if I point at an existing database during the installation and the database creation works fine if I choose an nonexisting database. But running them both together I get a SQL Server error.

```
*Cannot open database "Database" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'User'.!*
```

The error occurs when I create the MigrationRunner:

```
new MigrationRunner(migrationsAssembly, migrationContext, processor);
```

The SqlDatabase looks like this:

```
<sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase.IntegratedAuthentication' 
    Database='[DATABASE_NAME]' 
    Server='[DATABASE_SERVER]' 
    CreateOnInstall='yes' 
    DropOnUninstall='no' 
    ContinueOnError='no' />
```

In my log I can see that the CreateDatabase action is finished before the Migration starts, does anybody knows why this happends or how to get around it?

Comment: Have you looked at the log files and see if other errors are present?

You can generate them by running the msi file using the following options:

msiexec /i [Your MSI File] /l*v [Log File Name]

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/get_a_log.html

Comment: Yes that is how I recieved the error message. I compared it against the log from the try with existing database and there were no differences until this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to be missing the BinaryKey attribute for sql:SqlScript element?

Here's an excerpt from a working script that I wrote.

First, you define the scripts you wish to run. (i.e. the values for the BinaryKey attribute)

```
<Binary Id="CreateTablesBin" SourceFile="Database\[CreateScript]"></Binary>
<Binary Id="FillTablesBin" SourceFile="Database\[DataScript]"></Binary>
<Binary Id="DropTablesBin" SourceFile="Database\[RollbackScript]"></Binary>
```

And then you define a Feature to run the DB scripts.

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="DB Server Setup" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyWebComponents"/>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="IISConfiguration"/>
  <Component Id="IntegratedSecurity" Guid="[GUID Here]" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id="MySqlDatabase" Database="[DATABASE_NAME]" Server="[DATABASE_SERVER]" CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes" ContinueOnError="yes"> <!-- Don't specify user for Integrated Authentication / Win Authentication -->
      <sql:SqlScript Id="CreateTables" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="CreateTablesBin" ContinueOnError="no" />
      <sql:SqlScript Id="FillTables" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FillTablesBin"  ContinueOnError="no"/>
      <sql:SqlScript Id="DropTables" ExecuteOnInstall="no" ExecuteOnUninstall="yes" BinaryKey="DropTablesBin"  ContinueOnError="yes"/>
    </sql:SqlDatabase>
    <CreateFolder/>
  </Component>     
</Feature>
```

I'm not sure if you need the 2 ComponentGroupRef elements in there. I've included here in case it's needed.

Comment: No, I dont use a sql:SqlScript element at all, I use FluentMigrator to update the database.

Comment: How are you executing FluentMigrator in Wix? Through a Custom Action call? I've not come across FluentMigrator so I'm trying to understand it a bit better myself in conjunction with Wix.

Comment: Yes, through a Custom Action Call

Comment: Where is the CustomAction call in relation the <Feature> element that houses the DB Script? The Symptoms you describe sound like the DB Creation is in some sort of transitional state when the CustomAction tries to execute?

For example, my CustomAction calls are elements right under the main Product element, right after the Feature elements that house the Database components.

If yours is not the same, try moving the CustomAction call element?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an additional SQL Script when you only want to create the database. There are two things to check:

1. Which values do you define at runtime for the properties '[DATABASE_NAME]' and '[DATABASE_SERVER]' ?
2. Which user and which authentification method should be taken for the database login?

When you don't specify the 'user'-param inside SqlDatabase then automatically the current logged in user with his Windows Authentifaction is taken. If you don't want that, you have to define the 'user' on your own.

This examples takes the local installed SQL Express Server and current Win User:

```
<Property Id="SQLINSTANCE" Value="SQLEXPRESS" />
<Property Id="SQLSERVER" Value="LOCALHOST" />
...
<sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlDatabase" Database="Foobar" Server="[SQLSERVER]" Instance="[SQLINSTANCE]" CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes" />
```